# Strange characters on wordpress site - Not UTF8 Issue

Tags: database, encoding

I've imported WordPress post data onto a new site and noticed I have strange characters showing on pages and Blog posts.

It usually shows where apostrophes should be.

I've searched multiple solutions to UTF8 & latin1 solutions with success.  I've looked at my database and the characters are showing there too.

[image: strange characters in post]

[image: strange characters in database]

Comment: It looks like encoding was messed up during import.

Comment: You said: *"I've searched multiple solutions to UTF8 & latin1 solutions **with success**"*, don't you mean: "... **without success**"?

Comment: Do a database dump with `mysqldump`, and then search & replace the strange characters within the DB dump file, then reimport that database. I've solved a similar problem using the same method. This will only work if the error is from a single consistent encoding corruption.

Comment: Best guess that's a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), character code AD which would UTF-8 encode to [C2 AD](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00AD) where C2 = A-with-circumflex, and you've somehow stripped the circumflex too?, and AD = soft hyphen again, which may well not be printable and so the missing character symbol you've got there. So this might be UTF-8 and diacritics stripped, meaning you're unlikely to be able to automatically recover this: a manual search-replace is probably going to be best.

Comment: And FWIW I think your example "founded in" would be wrong with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

What is your database encoding? Try to switch to `utf8mb4`.

Alternatively, try to add one of these lines in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'latin1');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

or

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

or

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```